# Remove "sum of" from legend of pivot-chart in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I've created a pivot-chart based on a query and everything seems to be working except for the legend. The legend always displays "Sum Of Wait Times", "Count of Applications", etc. I can't seem to remove the "sum of". Anybody here have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, I think you are trying to show a simple chart in a relatively inflexible tool made to display pivot tables.

The box above the graph contains the calculation that is to be performed on the intersection of the categories below and the data series at the right. If you're working on raw data, this can be useful, but not if you've already calculated the sums in your query.

You're better off exporting the data to Excel.

Comment: I replaced Wait Times with Wait Times:Wait Times for the field in the query and I still get Sum Of Wait Times for the pivot chart legend.

Comment: Answer completely changed.